# How to disable chrome pop up that says You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer'

Tags: google-chrome, robotframework, selenium2library

When opened chrome it is opening with pop up message 'You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer'.

I am using latest chromedriver.exe to launch this.
And in robot framework using 'Open Browser chrome' keyword to launch the browser.

Is there any keyword to remove the pop up or any argument to pass which can remove that?  If so please tell me how the argument can be passed to chrome in robot framework automation.

Have tried many things but no luck . Can any one help on how to disable or remove the pop up.

Answer (score 1):

I used chromedriver 2.12 version (chromedriver_win32.zip) from the path http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.12/

with version 2.12 pop up is not appearing.

@google-chrome , selenium2library    -  is the pop up really required? If not 
please resolve this in latest chrome version too.